# (Rename current file with varirable) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, python-3.7

In the below; I believe I am doing the `os.rename` incorrectly. In the console it's finding and printing the right contents; but it is not doing the renaming.

What I really want to do is `rename` the current file, with the `MemberI` value, then move to a new directory. But at this point I'll settle to rename as is. MemberI is reporting accurately in console, just can't get the rename to perform. Any ideas.

```
for filename in os.listdir(config.Total):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        First_Name, Last_Name, Zip = filename.replace(".pdf",'').split()
        Name = First_Name + " " + Last_Name

        print(Name)
        print(Zip)
        data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)
        data2 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel2)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        header = df.iloc[0]
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
        header2 = df2.iloc[0]

        df = df[1:]
        df.rename(columns = header)
        df2 = df2[1:]
        df2.rename(columns = header2)

        row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(Name)].index.min()
        row_numberd12 = df[df['Member Address Line 3'].str.contains(Zip)].index.min()

        if row_numberd1 == row_numberd12: # When rows match of NameUp and Zip var in DF1
            rowMatched = row_numberd1
            print("Match Found")
            print(rowMatched)

            MemberID = df['ID'][rowMatched]
            MemberI = str(MemberID)

            os.rename(filename, MemberI)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the full path of the file that you're trying to rename `filename` only has the name of the file not the entire path

`os.rename(config.Total+'/'+filename, MemberI)`

if config.Total already has `/` then just

`os.rename(config.Total+filename, MemberI)`

Comment: Thanks, so with this; it's finding the file per 'filename' in directory as it should; but NOT renaming with the MemberI value (which it's also getting). It erroring as: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Comment: I am trying to rename as 'MemberI'!'

Comment: @CaptainRon [os.rename doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) does MemberI already exist bc that's why you get that error

Comment: I have it working now with close to your logic. BUT NOT IT'S NOT .pdf extension

Comment: @CaptainRon what is the value of `MemberI`? check if that ends with .pdf if it doesn't you can just append .pdf at the end of it like so `os.rename(..., MemberI+'.pdf')`

Comment: @CaptainRon did that answer your question?